# getting variable value dynamically

Tags: ruby, class, methods, metaprogramming

I have the following class

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name, :age, :address

  def initialize()
    self.name = "new user"
    self.age = 19
    self.address = "address" 
  end  


end
```

What I want if to have a method to get the assigned values to the attributes. Means, I have another method to get all the method names inside the above class

```
methods = self.public_methods(all = false)
```

and I can get the method name from that (I mean the getter of name etc..) and I want a way to pass that method name (which I have it as string) and get the return value of the method

Ex:

when I pass 'name' as the method name I should be able to get 'new user' as the value

hope I made my question clear, thanks in advance

** Please note, i have to use this way as my class has so many attributes and it has so many inherited classes. So accessing each and every attr individually is not possible :D

Comment: You already have `name` method defined by `attr_accessor :name`. What is wrong with that? I don't get your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That’s what `send` is for:

```
user = User.new
user.name        # => "new user"
user.send(:name) # => "new user"

getters = user.public_methods(false).reject { |m| m =~ /=$/ }
getters.each { |m| puts user.send(m) }
```

Using `instance_variable_get` is another option if you don’t have an accessor method:

```
user.instance_variable_get(:@name) # => "new user"
```

Using `public_methods` to get a list of attributes could be dangerous, depending on how you determine which methods to call. Instead, you could create your own class method which both defines the accessor and stores the attribute name for future use:

```
class User
  class << self
    attr_reader :fields

    def field (*names)
      names.flatten.each do |name|
        attr_accessor name
        (@fields ||= []) << name
      end
    end
  end

  field :name
  field :age
  field :address
end

user = User.new
user.name    = "Me"
user.age     = 22
user.address = "1234"

user.class.fields.each do |field|
  puts user.send(field)
end
```

Comment: hi todd, using getters = user.public_methods(false).reject { |m| m =~ /=$/ }
getters.each { |m| puts user.send(m) } says,'stack level too deep'

Comment: It sounds like your code which dynamically calls each accessor is in a method in the class itself, and so is being called by itself recursively. Using `public_methods` to find a list of attributes is probably not a good idea for this very reason. Instead, see the edit on my answer for a better solution.